# How to minimize to tray Thunderbird in KDE Plasma 5.2?

Tags: thunderbird, system-tray, plasma-5

I just tried Kubuntu 15.04. I installed Thunderbird with minimizetotray addon. But window disappears instead of minimize to tray. How can I fix it?

Comment: on my machine, thunderbird actually minimizes, but the icon in the taskbar (tasktray?) does not show, however I can access it by right click

Comment: So if you can't see anything in the tray, then presumably it's not minimising to tray?

Comment: There is also the add-on called "FireTray", but it crashes TB 38.0.1 for me. It worked fine for the last version of TB, though (31.7.0).

Answer (score 0):

In KDE5 the usual minimize-to-tray plugin works except you can't see icon but notification popup does appear so workaround is to add thunderbird app icon to panel to simulate its notification icon when minimized.  The only difference is the app icon is a little bigger than the one which appears after minimizing.  This way the behavior is exactly the same, in fact better since to open Thunderbird you click on the app icon just once.  Fire-tray plugin never worked for me in KDE5.

Answer (score 0):

Firetray does not work in current/newer versions of KDE's plasmashell, since the indicator rewrite.  The author of Firetray was working on actual indicator support, but unfortunately has decided to discontinue the project (https://foudil.fr/blog/209/the-web-is-not-the-platform/).  This is a shame, because I've not found any better option that works with thunderbird myself.

The only workaround I've found is to continue using the last release (0.6.0.1) of firetry and also install stalonetray.  If you configure stalonetray correctly, it can displaying the firetray icon (and any other legacy apps without real indicator support).

Comment: @tuxayo has mentioned the firetray fork: https://github.com/Ximi1970/FireTray
Original stackexchange link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278055/thunderbird-tray-icon-for-mail-notifications

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a little old, but the problem regarding minimizing Thunderbird to system tray still remains, at least for me having Debian 10 along with KDE Plasma desktop.

My today's workaround was successful! The firetray does not work the past years and finally I found the replacement.

https://github.com/Ximi1970/systray-x

They provide a lot of information in their README file, containing useful doc about installing in the most used Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, Arch, Fedora, OpenSuse, CentOS).

Comment: This approach does not work for the recent version of Thunderbird. I tried it, but in the end, it shows that it needs Thunderbird version 1.9x.

Comment: I currently use Debian 11 with KDE Plasma, having Thunderbird on version 78.14.0 and I confirm that systray-x works. This add-on provides settings to set the preferred action on minimizing and closing Thunderbird.